# LINQ to count occurrences

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, search, count

I have the following query which works great:

```
string[] Words = {"search","query","example"};

... Snip ...

var Results = (
    from a in q
    from w in Words
    where
        (
        a.Title.ToLower().Contains(w)
        || a.Body.ToLower().Contains(w)
        )
    select new
    {
        a,
        Count = 0
    }).OrderByDescending(x=> x.Count)
    .Distinct()
    .Take(Settings.ArticlesPerPage);
```

What I need it to do, is return `Count` which is the total occurrences of the words.  I'm going to weight it in favour of the title as well, example:

```
Count = (OccuranceInTitle * 5) + (OccurancesInBody)
```

I'm assuming I need to use the Linq.Count but I'm not sure how to apply it in this instance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what I came up with:

```
var query =
    from a in q
    from w in Words
    let title = a.Title.ToLower()
    let body = a.Body.ToLower()
    let replTitle = Regex.Replace(title, string.Format("\\b{0}\\b", w), string.Empty)
    let replBody = Regex.Replace(body, string.Format("\\b{0}\\b", w), string.Empty)
    let titleOccurences = (title.Length - replTitle.Length) / w.Length
    let bodyOccurences = (body.Length - replBody.Length) / w.Length
    let score = titleOccurences * 5 + bodyOccurences
    where score > 0
    select new { Article = a, Score = score };

var results = query.GroupBy(r => r.Article)
                   .OrderByDescending(g => g.Sum(r => r.Score))
                   .Take(Settings.ArticlesPerPage);
```

Counting occurrences is done with the (surprisingly) quick and dirty method of replacing occurrences with `string.Empty` and calculating based on the resulting string length. After the scores for each article and each word are calculated, I 'm grouping for each article, ordering by the sum of scores for all the words and taking a chunk out of the results.

I didn't fire up the compiler, so please excuse any obvious mistakes.

**Update:** This version uses regexes as in

```
Regex.Replace(title, string.Format("\\b{0}\\b", w), string.Empty)
```

instead of the original version's

```
title.Replace(w, string.Empty)
```

so that it now matches only whole words (the `string.Replace` version would also match word fragments).

Comment: Oh nice that's clever!  That even naturally weights longer words more, I like it!  Just to check though, title.Replace(w, string.Empty) will word with an array of words?

Comment: This is dangerous. It counts "Book" in the title "The Boring Bookkeepers". And similarly "a" is way overcounted in "The Aardvarks of Armadillo, Texas".

Comment: @Jason: Good catch. That can be fixed by using `Regex.Replace` instead of `string.Replace` -- I 'll get round to it.

Comment: @TomGullen: Actually it doesn't weigh longer words more because it divides the difference by `w.Length` as it stands (you need to scroll right to see it).

Comment: I've already filtered the words by removing stop words (so searching for "a file" would search for "file"), also "Book" matching in "Bookkeepers" is fine for my application.

Comment: @TomGullen: In the meantime I switched to `Regex.Replace` using "\b" to target word boundaries, so that now it only matches whole words :)

Comment: @Jon awesome that's so cool thanks :D  The search before worked but was pretty random in ordering this should be miles better, will test it soon!

Comment: @Jon I get a couple of queries giving a divide by 0 error, do you know of any way to tackle this in linq?

Comment: @TomGullen: Well the only division here is by `w.Length`, so maybe some empty strings slipped in there?

Comment: @Jon here it is in action by the way http://www.scirra.com/tutorials/search/1/beginners works a charm!